# read integers from a file into a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to read an unknown number of double values stored on separate lines from a text file into a vector called `rainfall`. My code won't compile; I am getting the error `no match for 'operator>>' in 'inputFile >> rainfall'` for the while loop line.  I understand how to read in from a file into an array, but we are required to use vectors for this project and I'm not getting it. I appreciate any tips you can give on my partial code below.

```
vector<double> rainfall;    // a vector to hold rainfall data

// open file    
ifstream inputFile("/home/shared/data4.txt");

// test file open   
if (inputFile) {
    int count = 0;      // count number of items in the file

    // read the elements in the file into a vector  
    while ( inputFile >> rainfall ) {
        rainfall.push_back(count);
        ++count;
    }

    // close the file
```

Comment: I suggest the iterator pair constructor. There are many examples online.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you should store it in a variable of type `double`. Seems you are doing `>>` to a vector, which is not valid. Consider the following code:

```
// open file    
ifstream inputFile("/home/shared/data4.txt");

// test file open   
if (inputFile) {        
    double value;

    // read the elements in the file into a vector  
    while ( inputFile >> value ) {
        rainfall.push_back(value);
    }

// close the file
```

As @legends2k points out, you don't need to use the variable `count`. Use `rainfall.size()` to retrieve the number of items in the vector.

Comment: Also the variable `count` is redundant since `rainfall.size()` would give you that information.

Answer (score 13):

You cannot use `>>` operator to read in the whole vector. You need to read one item at a time, and push it into the vector:

```
double v;
while (inputFile >> v) {
    rainfall.push_back(v);
}
```

You do not need to count the entries, because `rainfall.size()` will give you the exact count.

Finally, the most C++ -ish way of reading a vector is with istream iterators:

```
// Prepare a pair of iterators to read the data from cin
std::istream_iterator<double> eos;
std::istream_iterator<double> iit(inputFile);
// No loop is necessary, because you can use copy()
std::copy(iit, eos, std::back_inserter(rainfall));
```

Comment: I am researching the iterator concept at the suggestion of a poster above. It is a little complicated to me at this point, but I'm determined to understand this stuff! Thanks again for everyone's help.

Answer (score 10):

You could also do:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

...
std::istream_iterator<double> input(inputFile);
std::copy(input, std::istream_iterator<double>(),    
          std::back_inserter(rainfall));
...
```

assuming you like the STL.

Answer (score 6):

The input operator `>>` is not defined for inputting `double`s into a `std::vector`.

Instead construct the `std::vector` with two tokenizing input iterators for the input file.

Here's an example of how you can do it by using *only 2 lines of code*:

```
std::ifstream inputFile{"/home/shared/data4.txt"};
std::vector<double> rainfall{std::istream_iterator<double>{inputFile}, {}};
```

Another solution is to define the *input operator function* as:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, std::vector<double>& v) {
    double d;
    while (in >> d) {
        v.push_back(d);
    }
    return in;
}
```

Then you can use it as in your example:

```
std::vector<double> rainfall;
inputFile >> rainfall;
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the first approach. It's only 2 locs yes but I think it's not more readable. It's not immediately obvious what's happening. What's the second parameter? It's calling the vector's constructor taking two input iterators and an optional allocator. The second input iterator seems to be default constructed and pointing to nothing (NULL). Is this behavior standard confirm / defined somewhere? And how would one go about answering these questions?

Comment: @SebastianWilke When `{}` is used in this regard without a type it is treated as value or direct initialization (depending on if arguments are supplied or not) of the type deduced from the expected parameter type. So in this case it is equivalent with `std::istream_iterator<double>{}`. Value initializing `std::istream_iterator` produces the end-of-stream iterator ([see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator)).

Comment: @SebastianWilke I couldn't find an appropriate spec reference for how `{}` without type works, but it's usually referred to as "uniform initialization". Using value initialization (empty brackets) for end-of-stream iterators is standard usage (e.g. see [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)). For example: `for_each(std::istream_iterator<double>(my_istream), std::istream_iterator<double>())` will iterate `my_istream` until end-of-stream is reached.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using this input reader:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> parse_stream(std::istream &stream) {
    std::vector<T> v;
    std::istream_iterator<T> input(stream);
    std::copy(input, std::istream_iterator<T>(), std::back_inserter(v));
    return v;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input("/home/shared/data4.txt");
    std::vector<int> v = parse_stream<int>(input);
    for(auto &item: v) {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It allows you to use other stream types as well and is generic over type read.